# How can I find the command history if a user used a space before the command?

Tags: bash

Do we have any way to find out the command history if the user uses space before any command in the bash, because if user uses space before any command it won't show in history?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to see the spaces?

Comment: i dont want to see the spaces i want to see the command which run by user if user uses space before that command.Because normally if u put space before any command it wont be recorded in shell history.

Answer (score 14):

There is no way to find out now. You probably have a setting in `~/.bashrc` that intentionally hides all commands prepending with a space from history. To change this behaviour in the future, you can edit `~/.bashrc`. Look for this line

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace
```

and change it to

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

Comment: what will happen with the ignoredups?

Comment: `ignoredups` is in there by default, too. It will prevent consecutive duplicate commands from being written multiple times to the history. You can leave it in there if you like, or remove it if you do not want this behaviour.

Comment: i want to know one more little thing from you if we logged in through ssh to remote machine it will store logs in auth.log ,can we prevent to logged in to auth.log file?

Comment: @Sparhawk if I do `cd /tmp/` and then `rm -rf *` and then `cd /etc/` and then `rm -rf *` is the 2nd `rm -rf *` a duplicate?

Comment: @Rinzwind *consecutive* duplicates. For what you ask, `erasedups` is the right option, IIRC.

Comment: @khanthegeek I'm not sure about ssh and `auth.log`. If you ask a new question, you'd probably get more attention. Also, if this answer has answered your question, please click the tick icon on the left to accept.

Comment: @Rinzwind Exactly as muru says. In this example, it'd record all four commands as executed. P.S. please don't delete the contents of `/etc`. ;-)

Comment: @muru oh I was just wondering. I'd reaaaaaaaaaly want to know about the 2nd rm if it ever got executed ;-)

Comment: @Sparhawk then what is the difference of `ignoredups` and `ignoreboth`?

Comment: @KasiyA "A value of
              ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups." - from `man bash`

Comment: @Rinzwind Ahhhhh… That went way over my head.